# HTTP error 502 when deploying simple Identity Server 3 to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, identityserver3

i am playing around with Identity Server 3 for a project I am working on and i am trying to follow a tutorial I found here: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1

When running locally it works like expected but I want to deploy it to a web app in Azure. This is where I run into problems.

I receive an error:

```
    502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

Now I am trying to figure out if something is wrong with how I am setting up Identity Server or if I am not able to deploy something like this to a Web app in azure. Unfortunately i can't find any logs anywhere to give me any hints.

My startup class:

```
public sealed class Startup {
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.Map(
        "/core",
        coreApp => {
            coreApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions {
                SiteName = "Standalone Identity Server",
                SigningCertificate = Cert.Load(),
                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                        .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                        .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
                        .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get()),
                RequireSsl = true
            });
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed the tutorial about how to use identityserver3 to provide authentication services to an MVC application and a Web API [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html) to check this issue. It could work as expected on local side. Then I just deployed the identityserver project (identity server hosting application and client web application) and Web API project to Azure web app, then I checked it could work, you could refer to my web app [here](https://bruce-identityserver3.azurewebsites.net/).

I would recommend you could clone this git sample [IdentityServer3.Samples > MVC Authentication](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication) and test it on your local side, then change the related Uris to your azure side and deploy to azure to narrow this issue.